# Conditional form submition

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to conditionally submit one form or another. I have two forms, one main and one secondary. I want onsubmit of the main one to check if an input of the secondary has value and if yes submit the secondary.

Html code sample

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have tried having a javascript function on form1 onsubmit that will check the condition i want and will submit form2 if the condition is met. It didnt work though.

Comment: Where is your code? Show it, so someone can help to fix it. No code, no help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="checkTextField();" >
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" id="text" value="" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function checkTextField() {
    if (document.getElementById('text').value=="") {
        //alert("Field is empty");
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
    else{
        //alert("Field not empty");
        document.getElementById('form2').submit();
    }
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FavbL/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the propagation of the event from the first submit in order for the form to not be submitted. In jQuery:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  // Validate
  if (validated) {
    $('#form2').submit();
  }
}
```

NB: Code has not been tested.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do: you want to submit form2 through form1 but only if form2's input has a value?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="return someFunction()" action="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" action="POST">
    Some random value: <input type="text" name="something" value="">
</form>

<script>
    function someFunction() {

        // is the value blank? then don't do a thing. Otherwise submit
        if (document.forms["form2"]["something"].value != ''){
            document.forms["form2"].submit();
        }

        // always return false because we never want to submit form1...
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Having written that, I would much rather use JQuery.